# Is it still true that it's a bad idea to name attributes and relationships like any non-parameter method of NSObject or NSManagedObject?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I did some little experimentation on this.

I created an boolean attribute, named isFault. You know, that's a method of NSManagedObject and therefore actually not allowed for an attribute name because of KVC.

Simply, I used the default Core Data template for this test, but created the data model programmatically so I can show you what I do.

So here we go:

```
NSAttributeDescription *badAttr = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
[badAttr setName:@"isFault"];
[badAttr setAttributeType:NSBooleanAttributeType];
[badAttr setOptional:YES];
// don't want to occupy you with the whole, non-important rest ...
```

Next, I've modified the -insertNewObject method of the controller, added these lines:

```
// Assume: An managed object is created into the context, but not saved yet...
NSLog(@"isFault = %d", [newManagedObject isFault]); // 0 = NO

BOOL isFault = [[newManagedObject valueForKey:@"isFault"] boolValue];
NSLog(@"isFault = %d", isFault); // 0 = NO

[newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isFault"];

isFault = [[newManagedObject valueForKey:@"isFault"] boolValue];
NSLog(@"isFault = %d", isFault); // 0 = NO
```

Like you can see, I'm not able to set the isFault attribute to YES. It remains NO. Now, changing the attribute name to isFaultXYZ, will allow that.

So actually, what I wanted to ask is... since this stuff seems to depend on KVC, does the rule only apply to methods that **return something** and have no parameter? And does it matter what data type is returned? For example, -changedValues has no parameter and returns an NSDictionary. But since there is no attribute type like that, would this cause a collision anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the evidence. When naming the attribute changedValues, THIS happens after attempting to access it via KVC:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFDictionary boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1205680'
2010-06-10 14:52:40.232 CoreData[33996:207] Stack: (
    8035,
    4437,
    8825,
```